# How can I know app information from appstore programmatically

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application. In that I want to know some X application is available in AppStore or not programmatically. So please tell me how can I access and get the information from app store programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use for that purposes [iTunes Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). There are a lof of different filters by which you could find apps from iOS App Store and Mac App Store.

> The Search API allows you to place search fields in your website to search for content within the iTunes Store, App Store, iBookstore and Mac App Store. You can search for a variety of content; including apps, ebooks, movies, podcasts, music, music videos, audiobooks, and TV shows. You can also call an ID-based lookup request to create mappings between your content library and the digital catalog. Terms and conditions apply.
>
> The Affiliate Program allows you to earn a commission on qualifying revenue generated by clicks initiated from your website or app into the iTunes Store, App Store, iBookstore, and Mac App Store. For more information on the Affiliate Program, see http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates.

Comment: Did you go to the link: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html ?

Comment: Ok.Thank you.Your post is very helpful for me.

Comment: How can i know total apps names from appstore.

Comment: Not a single app.I want total iphone apps